# Error sintáctico en bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sintaxis

Actualmente estoy trabajando en Ubuntu 20.04, sin embargo el día de hoy al iniciar la terminal me apareció el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo el código de bash no ha sido modificado desde que lo instale, por lo cual me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de solucionarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es el script de bash por lo cual me resulta bastante extraño.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No pongas **nunca** tu correo electrónico en un sitio público o serás victima de spam continuamente. Por otra parte, léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender la dinámica del sitio. Tanto las preguntas como las respuestas van en este sitio, no por correo electrónico. Espera a que alguien te de una respuesta o un comentario solicitandote más información o aclaraciones.

Comment: El código debe ir en modo texto, no como imagen, para que podamos ayudarte mejor. Aún así, en tu caso diria que el error es que ese gestor denominado **conda** te ha comentado las lineas 126 y 128 haciendo que ese condicional no ejecute nada dentro de ese **if...then...else**, y de eso parece quejarse con lo del **Error sintáctico**.  O bien borras los comentarios (**#**) o bien borras ese **if...then...else** completo pues no hace nada ahora mismo (o eso intenta, pero te aparece ese error de sintaxis por lo explicado antes). Suerte

Comment: ¿En la línea 129 no debería ir un **fi** en vez de **if**?

Answer (score 0):

Cada `if` debe cerrarse con un `fi`. En la línea 122 tienes uno abierto que se cierra en la 130, pero luego tienes uno en la 125 que no se cierra, al igual que uno en la 129. Al parecer `conda` no gestionó bien el `.bashrc`. Si lo único que te interesa es que no salga el error, puedes comentar las líneas 124, 125, 127 y 129, agregando `#` al inicio de cada una de ellas. También puedes hacer lo siguiente

1. respaldar tu archivo `.bashrc`
2. eliminar todas las líneas a partir de la 119
3. ejecutar `conda init` para se se regeneren las líneas, esperando que esta vez no tengan problemas de sintaxis

Comment: Se agradece tu respuesta pero evita responder preguntas con carencias. El código no va como texto y tampoco cuesta nada copiarlo y pegarlo en la pregunta.

Comment: @Mateo: la pregunta está abierta, y lleva dos meses así. Creo que, o hay que cerrarla, o responderla.